# Five shortest strings from language $ L = \{0^{i}1^{i}| i \in \mathbb{N} , i > 0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I am studying for an upcoming exam, with an example question being.
Consider the following language,

$L = \{0^{i}1^{i}| i \in \mathbb{N} , i > 0\}$

Over the alphabet 
$A = \{0,1\}$

What are the five shortest strings in L?

I'm not 100% on how to interpret the language declaration.

Does the ordering of the string matter?

For example if $i =1 $.

Can we have the strings of "01" and "10"?

Or is the ordering of the language definition absolute where 0 must be first followed by a 1?

I have a possible idea for the answer where the ordering is absolute.

"01",
"0011",
"000111",
"00001111",
"0000011111"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $10$ doesn't belong to the language

Comment: If the ordering would not matter, you would be speaking about multisets rather than strings (or in the context of formal languages of Parikh sets). The very defintion of a string emphasizes the sequence (of symbols). So if something is given as a string, the ordering always matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering is relevant; the language cosists of all words with *first* some positive number of $0$'s, which is *then* followed by an equal number of $1$'s. So $10$ is not in your language, but $01$ is. Since we can't have the empty string ($i>0$ is required), you have successfully listed the five shortest strings at the end of your post.